# Codenameone Build Server Fail

Tags: java, codenameone

When trying to build my Android app to APK, the build server errors and fails to build. However, in the simulator the application works fine, and the class that errors I believe was created by the compiler (it is not one of which is inside the application)

Here is the error log: -

```
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no 

previous execution, etc.).
file or directory '/tmp/build4365298428607247775xxx/Main/src/debug/java', not found
Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.
/tmp/build4365298428607247775xxx/Main/src/main/java/com/<hidden this package name for privacy>/salestraining/MainStub.java:176: error: cannot find symbol
        Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable() { public void run() {i.destroy();} });
                                                                                ^
  symbol:   method destroy()
  location: variable i of type Main
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 7.165 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You removed the `destroy()` callback method from your main class. The main class should include 4 methods that don't throw exceptions:

```
public void init(Object) {}
public void start() {}
public void stop() {}
public void destroy() {}
```